# How does returning a __block variable works?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I've got the following code:

```
- (Transporter *) getTransporter:(NSNumber *)transporterId
{
    for(Transporter *transporter in transporters)
    {
         if([transporter.transporterId isEqualToNumber:transporterId])
         {
             return transporter;
         }
    }
    __block Transporter *transporter;

    [self requestTransporter:transporterId completion:^(NSObject *entity) {
        transporter = (Transporter* )entity;
     }];

    return transporter;
}
```

My question is: How does the __block Tranporter work? Does iOS wait till the variable got a value? Or do I have a nil value and later a object?

Does block methods work for methods with a return value?

Answer (score 3):

The __block keyword allow you to modify (read-write access) the variable, here transporter.
if your method requestTransporter in synchronous, he will be executed and will execute his completion block before the end of it's call.
You can also use the following pattern.

```
- (void) getTransporter:(NSNumber *)transporterId withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(Transporter*))completionBlock
{
    if(!completionBlock)
      return; //Avoid crashs.

    for(Transporter *transporter in transporters)
    {
         if([transporter.transporterId isEqualToNumber:transporterId])
         {
             completionBlock(transporter);
             return;
         }
    }

    [self requestTransporter:transporterId completion:^(NSObject *entity) {
        completionBlock((Transporter* )entity);
     }];
}
```

And use it like this:

```
// transporterId is an NSNumber containing your transporter id.
[self getTransporter:transporterId withCompletionBlock:^(Transporter *transporter) {
    // Execute your code using transporter object here.
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as blocks are asynchronous, transporter will be returned immediately, with no assigned entity.

Use a completion handler instead like this:

```
- (void) requestTransporter:(NSNumber *)transporterId withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(Transporter))completionBlock
{
  for(Transporter *transporter in transporters)
   {
     if([transporter.transporterId isEqualToNumber:transporterId])
     {
         completionBlock(transporter);
     }
   }
__block Transporter *transporter;

[self requestTransporter:transporterId completion:^(NSObject *entity) {
    transporter = (Transporter* )entity;
    completionBlock(transporter);
 }];

}
```

Comment: no need to declare `transporter` outside the block